# Unable to identify the .xml/file to update the host after installing Hadoop

Tags: hadoop

I encountered below mentioned error after installing Hadoop and executing `hadoop namenode -format` command.
Based on the displayed logs, I figured out that I need to update the "host" in the configuration. But, I am unable to find the exact location of the configuration file (.xml), which needs to be updated.

I am installing on Fedora on a single node. I am looking for your help in addressing this issue. Please point me to any specific link or documentation that could be helpful while debugging.

[hadoop@hadoop ~]$ hadoop namenode -format

```
Warning: $HADOOP_HOME is deprecated.
13/02/03 11:33:09 INFO namenode.NameNode: STARTUP_MSG: 
STARTUP_MSG: Starting NameNode
STARTUP_MSG:   host = java.net.UnknownHostException: hadoop: hadoop
13/02/03 11:34:27 INFO namenode.NameNode: SHUTDOWN_MSG: : 
SHUTDOWN_MSG: Shutting down NameNode at java.net.UnknownHostException: hadoop: hadoop
```

Answer (score 0):

Configuration files are in `$HADOOP_HOME/etc/hadoop`, where `$HADOOP_HOME` probably is `/usr/local/hadoop`. There can be several files with your hostname, you should check there.

Also, you should check `/etc/hosts`.